# Problems with appending a list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, append

I am recieving some `POST data` every three seconds (precisely 384 rows). These are stored in list called `data`. Then I would like to store them in list `helper`, which would be appended by `data` after every POST. For now I want to check the data in graph, so I need to convert `helper` into numpy array, which is called `myArr`.

```
data = json.loads(json_data)["data"] #I get some data
helper=[] #Then create list
helper.append(data) # And here I would like to add values to the end
myArr=np.asarray(helper)

self.send_response(200)
self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
self.end_headers()
self.wfile.write("") 


print (len(data))
print(type (data))
print (len(helper))
print(type (helper))
print (len(myArr))
print(type (myArr))
print data
```

But when I execute the code, the lenghts are not the same:

```
>>384
>><type 'list'>
>>1
>><type 'list'>
>>1
>><type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

And the list `data` content looks like this:

```
[[0.46124267578125, 0.0545654296875, 0.89111328125, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.46124267578125, 0.0545654296898, 0.89111328125, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.46124267578125, 0.0545654296875, 0.89111328125, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.4637451171875, 0.05804443359362, 0.8892822265625, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.4637451171875, 0.05804443359301, 0.8892822265625, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.4637451171875, 0.05804443359375, 0.8892822265625, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[etc.]]
```

I think there's just problem with dimensions of lists which I can not figure out.

Comment: If you want to concatenate lists, you can simply do ``list_c = list_a + list_b`` or in your case ``helper += data``

Answer (score 0):

You have a list to which you append another list, giving you a nested list with one item. Simple demo:

```
>>> data = [1,2,3]
>>> helper = []
>>> helper.append(data)
>>> helper
[[1, 2, 3]]
>>> len(helper)
1
```

I could not figure out from your question why you need the `helper` list at all, but to make a (shallow) copy issue `helper = data[:]` or `helper.extend(data)`. Since I'm not sure where you are going from here I'll leave this answer at telling you why your `helper` list has one element, for now.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I see now, that I am creating some sort of pyramid in 0. index of the list :D